# Fedora showing input/output error after 10-20mins of use

Tags: hard-drive, fedora

I am a new linux user. I recently bought a new sata hard disk of 160gb. I tried installing fedora on it but it failed. Tried installing debian on it but it also failed since the installation process stopped in the midst of installing. I went to the seller for him to check it out.It turned out to be a faulty sata cable which he replaced and he successfully installed Windows 7 on it on the first go.

After that I formatted windows and installed fedora 23 xfce spin on my old computer with 2gb DDR2 ram and then I was able to successfully install it. For first day I ran it for a short period of time and it worked fine but on second day when I left it on for downloading a file from my server, I checked it in the morning and its screen saver gave me no option to enter my password to login. I resorted to turning it off via pressing the power button.

Third day when I turned it on again and used for 2 hours it froze giving input/output error. Tried to install google chrome, tomahawk music player it gave input/output error after downloading the packages. Whether I clicked on any icon, even terminal, any file, it gave input/output error. Fourth day after 10-20 mins of use it froze and again gives input/output error.

I tried running dmesg when the system gave the error but it also gives input/output error.

Thankfully, I was able to click on shut down button when it gave errors like this in dmesg:

```
    Input/output error on block 233171008
    Input/output error on block 233171008
    Input/output error on block 242061800
    Input/output error on block 242061928
    Input/output error on block 242061928
```

I tried running `fsck` from a live usb running fedora and it gives output of file system as clean. It freed some inodes but that's all.

Tried `e2fsck`; it also gave same output i.e clean. It also freed some inodes and that's all. I forced running again but this time it just displayed it as clean.

I thought I had problems with my installation but it looks like its all good. Help please!

Comment: While it's possible in principle that you're hitting a kernel bug or FS driver bug, that would be unusual to show up in a stable release, and would probably affect a lot of users. My guess is your HDD is bad.

Comment: Replace the HDD.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly actually due to a problem with the new disk. Disk failure follows a [bathtub curve](https://superuser.com/questions/350415/mean-time-to-failure-mttf-when-disk-manufacturers-post-this-how-should-you-i/350417#350417), so failures early on are common.

You could get further verification by installing `smartmontools` (if not already installed), and then running `smartctl -a /dev/sda`. But, mostly, since your disk is new, I'd say to return it immediately for replacement.

Comment: Actually, I don't think the problem is with the disk, but problem is with Fedora. I am facing this very same issue on my Inspiron laptop (`Input/Output error` after a few minutes of usage). And guess what? This happens only with Live usb of Fedora, not Ubuntu, not Debian, not openSUSE, I've tried them all!

Comment: Wait, hold on. Is this _all_ on a live USB? From your question, I thought that was a diagnostic tool you used.

Comment: Yup. I'm using live USB to try out f23. After 10-20 minutes of usage, I get an I/O error whenever I try to open a program or give a terminal command. When I shut down, [this](http://imgur.com/gLnFNWi) is what the console says. (I'm not OP, btw).

Comment: Still having this same issue with Fedora 38, smartctl doesn't give any errors!! Sorry but this is a troublesome issue! I've used this laptop with Windows 10 for about 8 months without issues. My system becomes completely non-responsive!